# OnPolylineClickListener Slow

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've written a simple test for OnPolylineClickListener.  Everything works, but there is **about a second delay** (at least on the emulator) before the click is registered and the log/toast appear.  **Is this normal?**  Can it be sped up?

Here is the code, in case it matters:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        LatLng melbourne = new LatLng(-38, 145);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(melbourne).title("Marker in Melbourne"));

        mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(sydney, melbourne).clickable(true).color(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0)));

        mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
        Log.i("PolylineTest", "Clicked line!");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked line!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have found emulators to respond slowly to many requests and in general not respond as a real device. As a consequence I no longer test apps with the emulator.

Comment: I've checked your code and it's working great, you should use an actual device instead of emulators, they're really slow.

Comment: Thanks all, I wasn't testing on my device because I couldn't find my USB A to USB C adapter.  Normally the emulator works fine for proof of concept, but I guess not for this.  Once I found my cable and started testing on my phone, it was fine.